# SQL Server 2008 auto connect to server when opening Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, autologin

Is there any tip to make SQL Server Management Studio auto connect to the server that opened last time?

For example that I've opened three connection this moment.

```
1.
Connection1: 123.123.123.1
Login ID: sa1
Password: pwd1

2.
Connection1: 123.123.123.2
Login ID: sa2
Password: pwd2

3.
Connection1: 123.123.123.3
Login ID: sa3
Password: pwd3
```

My question is how to make it connects to above server automatically while next time opens the Management Studio, and I don't need type connection IP, ID and password again.

My SQL Server version is 2008.

Comment: pass in via command line parameter. refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-management-studio/ssms-utility

Answer (score 0):

As Far as i knew:

SQL Server need to use The Database Engine to point you which connection do you want to open.

There's no any option to open your previous server automatically unless you have to login to that specific server first.

**The Second option:**

You can use `register` to `Save` the server you want by `right` clicking your current `working server` >> select `register`.. >> click `save`

After you close Management Studio then try to open it again:
On `menu` Click `View` > expand `database engine` > select the server you `registered` earlier to `automatically` open for you.

Make sure before you Login, you checked the checkbox option `Remember password`.
if not, you'll be back to Login again after clicking on `View>Database Engine>Servers`

Hope it helps.